# Wordpress show featured image sorted by subtitle

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to sort this array by the subtitle. I want to show only featured images, where the subtitle is "anwesend". I tried different things, but nothing is working. Could you please support me in this task?

here is the code of this array.

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
      'parent' => $post->ID,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
  ); 
  $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
  <div style="max-width:1240px;"> 
  <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
   <div class="box">
      <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
      <span class="tagesplan_title"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span>
      <center><span class="thumbnail_box"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?></span></center>
      <span class="status2"><?php echo get_the_subtitle($page); ?></span>
      <span class="desc"><?php echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'desc', true); ?></span>
      </a>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```